# Extract substring from ldap search

Tags: php, string, ldap, preg-match

I have a ldap search output like this:

> CN=ABC0000001,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net
>   CN=ABC4257635,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net
>   CN=ABC1231231,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net
>   CN=XYZ0345432,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net
>   CN=XYZ0546322,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net
>   CN=ABC5465747,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net

I want to print only the CommonName part based on the ^ABC pattern, so I get the following result:

> ABC0000001
>   ABC4257635
>   ABC1231231
>   ABC5465747

It seems that preg_match could be the tool to achieve that, however I'm trying to get the substring between "CN=ABC" and the first "," character with the following line with no success (it returns NULL):

```
preg_match('CN=(([ABC]+)(\d+)),',$string,$m); echo $m[1];
```

where `$string` should be every line in my ldap output.

How can I get my desired result?

Comment: `/CN=(\w*),/` ?

Comment: This should match the expected output. But your request look like you are trying to get the number part? In that case `CN=(([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)),`

Comment: May you check https://regex101.com/r/Qmbz25/1 and Edit your question to be accurate and clear this point ?

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks, this regex gives the correct matches: `CN=(([ABC]+)(\d+)),`, but when applying it to my code it doesn't provide any output. I will edit my php try in the question.

Comment: `print_r($matches);` and `print_r($string);` verify your input and output because it should provide the right output if the input is correct.

Comment: The regex must be enclose with delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( preg_match('/^CN=(ABC\d+)/', "CN=ABC0000001,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=net", $m ) )
{
    echo $m[1];
}
```